# Left join with 2 table giving results of 1 table only

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 tables below:

Reasons_Trans:

```
   RTId | RId   | Label     | Lang      | 
_________________________________________________________
    1   | 1     |  No car   | English   | 
_________________________________________________________
    2   | 2     | No fuel   | English   |
```

Reasons:

```
   ReId | RId   | Active| OfficeId
_________________________________________________________
    1 | 1   |  True |   1
_________________________________________________________
    2 | 2   | True  |   1
```

Employee_Reason:

```
   ERId | RId   | EmpId | 
_________________________________________________________
    1   | 1     |  1    |    
_________________________________________________________
    2   | 2     |  1    |  
_________________________________________________________
    3   | 0     |  1    |
```

Employee_Reason_Trad:

```
   Id | ERId    | Label     | Lang
_________________________________________________________
    1 | 3       |  No in    | English
_________________________________________________________
    2 | 3       |  Out in   | English
```

I need to get the following:
For officeID = 1 (or any office), I need to get the Reasons of a particular employee + all reasosn available for that office.

So my query is as follows:

```
select rt.Label, ert.Label
from Reasons r
join Reasons_Trans rt
on r.RId = rt.RId and rt.Lang = 'English'
left join Employee_Reason er
on r.RId = er.RId
left join Employee_Reason_Trad ert
on er.ERId = ert.ERId and ert.Lang = 'English'
where er = 1 and r.OfficeId = 1
```

However this is not returning me the results of the Employee_Reason_Trad.

The output of the query should be:

> No car, No fuel, No in, Out in

Any idea of what is wrong with my query?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the logic behind the data, but the expected result will be returned if you change your last join. Instead of `on er.ERId = ert.ERId` it must join `on er.ERId = ert.Id`:

```
select rt.Label, ert.Label
from Reasons r
join Reasons_Trans rt
on r.RId = rt.RId and rt.Lang = 'English'
left join Employee_Reason er
on r.RId = er.RId
left join Employee_Reason_Trad ert
on er.ERId = ert.Id and ert.Lang = 'English'
where er = 1 and r.OfficeId = 1
```

Returns:

```
Label     Label
--------- -------
No car    No in
No fuel   Out in
```

Comment: No, issue is the left join with Employee_Reason table which only return those rows RId in  Reasons.  I can't do a join since the Employee_Reason table can not have any data for the given employee.